# Using fql to get the frends list from facebook throws an error

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

when I try to use fql to get  the frends list  from facebook  appear a error.

`"(#803) Cannot query users by their username (fql.query)"`

my code:

`String fields = "uid, first_name, last_name, "
String query = "SELECT " + fields + " FROM user WHERE uid = me()";`

anyboy can help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FQL is deprecated since v2.1, so you'll need a v2.0 app to be able to use FQL queries.

With the introduction of v2.0, the `username` field was deprecated as well. You cannot use it anymore.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_1
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Because you are trying to fetch the detail for the user and from v2.0 facebook has stop responding the result for the user(NOT PAGE).
You will get the response if you put the page name instead of user's username.

If you want to know something more about this then visit below link.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0